# Java Mail: get UniqueID from Message

Tags: java, email, jakarta-mail

I need a **uniqueID** from a message Object to save this in my database.
Afterwards I´m able to search for this UID in my database and can add other properties, like "emailTrackingActive" etc.

a) Is there a possibility to get a whole UID for a Email Inbox or is it always only per folder? Currently I´m getting this as you can see in the code.

Currently I´m doing the following as you can see in the code: 
After I´ve send the message, I copy the message into my "Sent" folder and then I want to get the UID and save it in the database.

With "EmailHelperClass" I´m getting Store etc. 
I think it should be clear and I will not post this code...

```
private void copyIntoSentAndSaveInDatabase(EmailHelperClass email, final Message msg){

    final Store store = email.getMailConfiguration().getWriteStore();

    final Folder folder = (Folder) store.getFolder("Sent");
    if (folder.exists() == false) {
        folder.create(Folder.HOLDS_MESSAGES);
    }
    folder.open(Folder.READ_WRITE);
    folder.appendMessages(new Message[] { msg });

    // Get UniqueID
    UIDFolder uf = (UIDFolder) folder;
    Long messageId = uf.getUID(msg);

    // Todo Update in DB etc
}
```

But now I´m getting the following error message:

> java.util.NoSuchElementException: Message does not belong to this
>   folder

What is wrong here?

Comment: Hi, Do u get any solution regarding this, i am also facing the same issue. Please let me know if you get the solution to solve this error. Thanks in advance

Comment: No, I´m sorry I haven´t found any solution

Comment: i found the solution for this issue.

Comment: can you share it, please.

Comment: @shekharshrivastava can you share it, please. Thank you

Comment: sorry for the late reply

Answer (score 0):

Hi all you need to change folder to IMAPFolder

```
final Store store = email.getMailConfiguration().getWriteStore();

final IMAPFolder folder = (IMAPFolder) store.getFolder("Sent");
folder.open(Folder.READ_WRITE)
```

with the help of this folder fetch all your messages i have write the below method to get the UID of the message

```
private long getMessagesUID(UIDFolder folder,javax.mail.message message){
     try{
      return folder.getUID(message)
       }catch(Exception ex)
       {
       ex.printStackTrace();
       }
```

Let me know in case of any query.

Comment: Yes as i have a requirement related to IMAP.